# The file or folder /media/partitionname/foldername does not exist. Kubuntu. Dolphin

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, ntfs, kde4, dolphin

Situation.
- after file backup
- realigned my hard drive as disk utility was showing misalignment errors.
- first tried resize/move on the partition named in the title, which failed.
- simply deleted the partition and reformatted
- restored files to revived partition. (with same partition label)
- linux on bootup looks for the old one, asking user to press S for skip or M for manual
- so /etc/fstab is edited to delete the old entry with the old UUID.
- things work fine

**However**:  Dolphin (kde file manager) still shows error message: The file or folder /media/partitionname/foldername does not exist.

How does one stop Dolphin from looking for the old location of partitionname?

Note: NTFS configuration tool (ntfs-config) is also installed to automatically mount partitionname.  This was already being regularly used before the partition was restored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: simply edited .kde/share/config/dolphinrc to remove homeurl entry which had been previously set on the partition when it still existed